# convert sequelize operators to string

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a problem with sequelize where option in nodejs.
I have this where option

```
const whereOption = {
  publishedAt: {
    [Op.gt]: new Date(),
  },
  title: {
    [Op.or]: ['My Post', 'Another Post'],
  },
};
```

the problem is that when I convert this option to string my output will be this

{"publishedAt":{},"title":{}}

I am using JSON.stringfy() and apparently it can't to make sequelize operators to string,

how can I solve this problem?